# Terraform EKS:Cluster is already at the desired configuration with desired configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I have  created an EKS cluster using terraform after creation I am trying to update one parameter which is `endpoint_public_access=false`

But I am getting the following  error

> Error: error updating EKS Cluster
>   (ec1-default-ics-common-alz-eks-cluster) config:
>   InvalidParameterException: Cluster is already at the desired
>   configuration with endpointPrivateAccess: false ,
>   endpointPublicAccess: true, and Public Endpoint Restrictions:
>   [0.0.0.0/0] {   ClusterName: "ec1-default-ics-common-alz-eks-cluster",
>   Message_: "Cluster is already at the desired configuration with
>   endpointPrivateAccess: false , endpointPublicAccess: true, and Public
>   Endpoint Restrictions: [0.0.0.0/0]" }   on
>   ../../terraform-hli-aws-eks/eks_cluster/main.tf line 1, in resource
>   "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster":    1: resource "aws_eks_cluster"
>   "eks_cluster" {

Here is the terraform plan

```
 ~ resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
        arn                       = "<arn>"
        certificate_authority     = [
            {
                data = "<datat>"
            },
        ]
        created_at                = "2020-03-09 08:59:28 +0000 UTC"
        enabled_cluster_log_types = [
            "api",
            "audit",
        ]
        endpoint                  = "<url>.eks.amazonaws.com"
        id                        = "ec1-default-ics-common-alz-eks-cluster"
        identity                  = [
            {
                oidc = [
                    {
                        issuer = "<url>"
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
        name                      = "ec1-default-ics-common-alz-eks-cluster"
        platform_version          = "eks.9"
        role_arn                  = "<url>"
        status                    = "ACTIVE"
        tags                      = {
            "Environment" = "common"
            "Project"     = "ics-dlt"
            "Terraform"   = "true"
        }
        version                   = "1.14"

      ~ vpc_config {
            cluster_security_group_id = "sg-05ab244e50689862a"
            endpoint_private_access   = false
            endpoint_public_access    = true
          ~ public_access_cidrs       = [
              - "0.0.0.0/0",
            ]
            security_group_ids        = [
                "sg-081527f14bf1a6646",
            ]
            subnet_ids                = [
                "subnet-08011850bb5b7d7ca",
                "subnet-0fab8917fdc533eb3",
            ]
            vpc_id                    = "vpc-07ba84e4a6f54d91f"
        }
    }
```

**Terraform code**

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
  name     = var.name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.arn
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids              = var.cluster_subnet_ids
    endpoint_private_access = var.endpoint_private_access
    endpoint_public_access  = var.endpoint_public_access
    public_access_cidrs     = var.public_access_cidrs
    security_group_ids      = var.security_group_ids
  }
  enabled_cluster_log_types = var.enabled_cluster_log_types

  tags = var.tags

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_cluster_role-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_cluster_role-AmazonEKSServicePolicy,
  ]
}


data "template_file" "eks_cluster_role" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/roles/cluster_role.json")}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_cluster_role" {
  name               = var.cluster_role_name
  assume_role_policy = data.template_file.eks_cluster_role.rendered
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_cluster_role-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_cluster_role-AmazonEKSServicePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.name
}
```

Comment: I know this is not what you are looking for.. but - try to update this field using the cli - `aws eks update-cluster-config \
    --region region \
    --name dev \
    --resources-vpc-config endpointPublicAccess=true,endpointPrivateAccess=true`

Comment: Sorry I can't use the solution I need TF way since all of our infra is managed by TF

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the Terraform code for `aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster`? If you could include a [mcve] that allows this to be reproduced then that would be even better.

Comment: I know, and as i mentioned.. this is not the best practice. but it looks like terraform detect this change as a critical change and as that require to destroy the cluster before updating

Comment: @ydaetskcoR question updated with code snippet

Comment: What is the content of `var.public_access_cidrs` when you are getting that plan output?

Comment: As of I am setting that variable as a default `[]`, plan output is `known after apply`

Comment: What happens if you set it to `["0.0.0.0/0"]`?

Comment: That I am trying now, let you know once completed the apply

Comment: It returns the same `known after apply`

Comment: Still, I have the same error TF always try to modify the `public_access_cidrs` even if it's not changed. `~ public_access_cidrs       = [
              - "0.0.0.0/0",
            ]`

Answer (score 1):

if the cluster has this setting:

```
endpoint_public_access  = true
```

then you need to "disable" this setting:

```
public_access_cidrs     = null
```

you could do something like this:

```
public_access_cidrs     = var.endpoint_public_access == true ? var.public_access_cidrs : null
```